# ECS instance can't connect to itself behind network load balancer

Tags: amazon-elb

We've got a service (java-based) and mysql both running as ECS services.  The service wants to communicate to a mysql database through a network ELB.

When our service and the mysql database are running on the same EC2 instance, it can't connect to the mysql database.  I can reproduce this using telnet - if I telnet to the mysql database through the ELB from another computer I can connect, but if I ssh to the EC2 instance that mysql is running on and then try to telnet to it through the ELB, it just hangs.

What's going on?

Comment: Why do you want to communicate to a database through a Load Balancer? Do you have multiple databases? Also, what are the Security Group configurations in use?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm a bit hesitant to answer your question because I fear it's addressing the context of the question and not the heart of it and I may have obfuscated by giving TMI. Think of the problem as this simple question: "I can't connect from an ECS service to another ECS service running on the same machine when I route through a network load balancer". To answer your question, we're doing it so we can assign a port number to a database and then the clients that connect to it don't ever need to care where it's located.  We can move it to another anywhere as long as it keeps its port.

Answer (score 0):

If an instance needs to connect to itself via a network load balancer I think the only way to get it to work is to disable client IP preservation on the load balancer target group.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html

> Check whether client IP preservation is enabled on your target group.
> Load balancers with client IP preservation enabled do not support
> hairpinning or loopback. If an instance is a client of a load balancer
> that it's registered with, and it has client IP preservation enabled,
> the connection succeeds only if the request is routed to a different
> instance. Otherwise, the source and destination IP addresses are the
> same and the connection times out.
>
> If an instance must send requests to a load balancer that it's
> registered with, do one of the following:
>
> Disable client IP preservation.
>
> Ensure that containers that must communicate, are on different
> container instances.